# Finding the closed form of $\int_0^1 \frac{(1-x+x\log x)\operatorname{Li}_3(x)}{x(x-1) \log x} \ dx$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, definite-integrals, improper-integrals

$\def\Li{{\rm{Li}}}$Here I have a question I just received, and  still trying to find a proper starting point

$$\int_0^1 \frac{(1-x+x\log x)\Li_3(x)}{x(x-1) \log x} \ dx$$

What starting point would you propose?

Comment: What evidence do we have that this integral is likely to have a closed form?

Comment: @Alizter Repeated integration by parts can reduce the integral to a relatively simple log-log integral for which I'm fairly confident a closed-form exists.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I believe the closed form proposed in Chris's sis' answer is correct. Here's the derivation I used:

$$\begin{align}
\mathcal{I}
&=\int_{0}^{1}\frac{\left(1-x+x\ln{(x)}\right)\operatorname{Li}_{3}{\left(x\right)}}{(x-1)x\ln{(x)}}\,\mathrm{d}x\\
&=\lim_{z\to1^-}\int_{0}^{z}\left(\frac{\operatorname{Li}_{3}{\left(x\right)}}{x-1}-\frac{\operatorname{Li}_{3}{\left(x\right)}}{x\ln{(x)}}\right)\,\mathrm{d}x\\
&=\lim_{z\to1^-}\left[\int_{0}^{z}\frac{\operatorname{Li}_{3}{\left(x\right)}}{x-1}\,\mathrm{d}x-\int_{0}^{z}\frac{\operatorname{Li}_{3}{\left(x\right)}}{x\ln{(x)}}\,\mathrm{d}x\right]\\
&=\lim_{z\to1^-}\left[\frac12\operatorname{Li}_{2}^2{\left(z\right)}+\operatorname{Li}_{3}{\left(z\right)}\ln{\left(1-z\right)}-\int_{0}^{z}\frac{\operatorname{Li}_{3}{\left(x\right)}}{x\ln{(x)}}\,\mathrm{d}x\right]\\
&=\lim_{z\to1^-}\left[\frac12\operatorname{Li}_{2}^2{\left(z\right)}+\operatorname{Li}_{3}{\left(z\right)}\ln{\left(1-z\right)}-\ln{\left(-\ln{\left(z\right)}\right)}\operatorname{Li}_{3}{\left(z\right)}+\int_{0}^{z}\frac{\ln{\left(-\ln{\left(x\right)}\right)}\operatorname{Li}_{2}{\left(x\right)}}{x}\,\mathrm{d}x\right]\\
&=\frac{\pi^4}{72}+\int_{0}^{1}\frac{\ln{\left(-\ln{\left(x\right)}\right)}\operatorname{Li}_{2}{\left(x\right)}}{x}\,\mathrm{d}x\\
&=\frac{\pi^4}{72}-\int_{0}^{1}\frac{\ln{\left(x\right)}\ln{\left(1-x\right)}}{x}\,\mathrm{d}x+\int_{0}^{1}\frac{\ln{\left(x\right)}\ln{\left(1-x\right)}\ln{\left(-\ln{\left(x\right)}\right)}}{x}\,\mathrm{d}x\\
&=\frac{\pi^4}{72}-\zeta{(3)}+\int_{0}^{1}\frac{\ln{\left(x\right)}\ln{\left(1-x\right)}\ln{\left(-\ln{\left(x\right)}\right)}}{x}\,\mathrm{d}x\\
&=\frac{\pi^4}{72}-\zeta{(3)}-\frac14\int_{0}^{1}\frac{\ln^2{\left(x\right)}}{1-x}\,\mathrm{d}x+\frac12\int_{0}^{1}\frac{\ln^2{\left(x\right)}\ln{\left(-\ln{\left(x\right)}\right)}}{1-x}\,\mathrm{d}x\\
&=\frac{\pi^4}{72}-\frac32\zeta{(3)}+\frac12\int_{0}^{1}\frac{\ln^2{\left(x\right)}\ln{\left(\ln{\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)}\right)}}{1-x}\,\mathrm{d}x\\
&=\frac{\pi^4}{72}-\frac32\zeta{(3)}+\frac12\left[\int_{0}^{1}\frac{x^{p-1}\ln^2{\left(x\right)}\ln{\left(\ln{\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)}\right)}}{1-x}\,\mathrm{d}x\right]_{p=1}\\
&=\frac{\pi^4}{72}-\frac32\zeta{(3)}+\frac12\left[\int_{0}^{1}\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}x^{k+p-1}\ln^2{\left(x\right)}\ln{\left(\ln{\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)}\right)}\,\mathrm{d}x\right]_{p=1}\\
&=\frac{\pi^4}{72}-\frac32\zeta{(3)}+\frac12\left[\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\int_{0}^{1}x^{k+p-1}\ln^2{\left(x\right)}\ln{\left(\ln{\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)}\right)}\,\mathrm{d}x\right]_{p=1}\\
&=\frac{\pi^4}{72}-\frac32\zeta{(3)}+\frac12\left[\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{\partial^2}{\partial p^2}\int_{0}^{1}x^{k+p-1}\ln{\left(\ln{\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)}\right)}\,\mathrm{d}x\right]_{p=1}\\
&=\frac{\pi^4}{72}-\frac32\zeta{(3)}+\frac12\left[\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{\partial^2}{\partial p^2}\left(-\frac{\gamma+\ln{\left(k+p\right)}}{k+p}\right)\right]_{p=1}\\
&=\frac{\pi^4}{72}-\frac32\zeta{(3)}+\frac12\left[\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\left(\frac{3-2\gamma}{(k+p)^3}-\frac{2\ln{\left(k+p\right)}}{(k+p)^3}\right)\right]_{p=1}\\
&=\frac{\pi^4}{72}-\frac32\zeta{(3)}+\frac12\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\left(\frac{3-2\gamma}{(k+1)^3}-\frac{2\ln{\left(k+1\right)}}{(k+1)^3}\right)\\
&=\frac{\pi^4}{72}-\frac32\zeta{(3)}+\frac12\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\left(\frac{3-2\gamma}{k^3}-\frac{2\ln{\left(k\right)}}{k^3}\right)\\
&=\frac{\pi^4}{72}-\gamma\zeta{(3)}-\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\left(\frac{\ln{\left(k\right)}}{k^3}\right)\\
&=\frac{\pi^4}{72}-\gamma\zeta{(3)}+\zeta^{\prime}{(3)}.\\
\end{align}$$

Comment: A very good job (+1)

Comment: @Chris'ssis Thanks. Is this roughly how you arrived at the result, or did you do something different? Just curious.

Comment: I did something similar to your work, and then I noted a second way that requires no use of polylogarithm.

Answer (score 7):

$\def\Li{{\rm{Li}}}$Thanks to @David H's comment I got that

$$\int_0^1 \frac{(1-x+x\log x)\Li_3(x)}{x(x-1) \log x} \ dx=\frac{5}{4}\zeta(4)-\gamma \zeta(3)+\zeta'(3)$$ that is proving to be numerically correct.
Here I have a question I just received, and  still trying to find a proper starting point

*An alternative way*

$$\int_{0}^{1}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left(\frac{x^n}{n^3(x-1)}-\frac{x^{n-1}}{n^3\ln{(x)}}\right) \ dx $$
$$=-\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^3}\int_{0}^{1}\left(\frac{x^{n-1}}{\ln{(x)}}+\frac{x^n}{1-x}\right) \ dx \tag{*}$$
$$=-\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\log(n)-\psi(n+1)}{n^3}$$
$$=\frac{5}{4}\zeta(4)-\gamma \zeta(3)+\zeta'(3)$$
where in $(*)$ I use the **Proposition $2.16.$** from [this paper](http://arxiv.org/pdf/0709.3446v2.pdf).

**Q.E.D.**

Comment: would you mind to give some details?

Comment: @tired done as requested